# IIS 6.0 Windows Server 2003 - how to iterate through all websites using powershell?

Tags: iis-6, powershell

How can I iterate through all the websites hosted on an IIS 6.0 (Windows Server 2003) using powershell?

Is there a way to do it using WmiObject ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you simply looking for a list of their names or do you expect some sort of site object to be passed back to be acted upon?

Comment: Not just listing the sites, but be able to iterate through each website and add new HttpCustomHeaders to it in IIS6.0.

Answer (score 3):

List them using ADSI or WMI as follows --

```
#ADSI
$iis = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC" 
$iis.psbase.children | where { $_.schemaClassName -eq "IIsWebServer"} | select ServerComment

#WMI
Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" | Select ServerComment
```

To add a new HttpCustomHeader as you've mentioned in your comment, I think you can use the following technique.  Please test thoroughly for I did not.

```
$wmiSiteArray = Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2"

foreach ($site in $wmiSiteArray)
{
  $path = $site.name + '/root'
  $vdir = [wmi]"root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsWebVirtualDirSetting='$path'"
  $bindingClass= [wmiclass]'root\MicrosoftIISv2:HttpCustomHeader'
  $newHeader = $bindingClass.CreateInstance()
  $newHeader.KeyName = "CustomHeader: BlahBlah"
  $newHeader.value = $null
  $vdir.HttpCustomHeaders += $newHeader.PSObject.BaseObject
  $vdir.Put()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575442/getting-all-virtual-directories-for-a-iis6-web-site-using-wmi

has this solution:

```
Get-WmiObject IIsWebVirtualDir -namespace "ROOT\MicrosoftIISv2" | `
     Where-Object { $_.name -like "W3SVC/1/*" }
```